# react router dom v6.2.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hello everyone I have an issue with react-router-dom v6.2.1

```
const MainRoutes = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path={"/"} element={<Login/>}/>
            <Route path={"/dashboard*"} render={<PrivateRoutes/>}/>
        </Routes>
    );
};


const PrivateRoutes = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/dashboard/" element={<Dashboard/>}/>
            <Route path="/dashboard/:id" element={<Book/>}/>
        </Routes>
    );
};
```

/dashboard and /dashboard/:id render blank for me

Comment: It looks like you meant to use `render={<PrivateRoutes />}`

Comment: yes I misspelled here

Comment: It looks like you meant to use `element={<PrivateRoutes/>}`

Comment: Also your path `/dashboard*` seems not correct, maybe this is what you are looking for: `<Route path={"dashboard/*"} element={<PrivateRoutes/>} />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
export const MainRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path={"/"} element={<Login />} />
      <Route path={"/dashboard/*"} element={<PrivateRoutes />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/:id" element={<Book />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
```

you should use like this

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Answer (score -1):

## hi hasan

1. you need to change

```
<Route path={"/dashboard*"} render={<PrivateRoutes/>}/>
```

to

```
<Route path={"/dashboard/*"} element={<PrivateRoutes/>}/>
```

have a look on [this post](https://dev.to/iamandrewluca/private-route-in-react-router-v6-lg5)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).